# TEdgeBrowser.Navigate failing to load, no error raised

Tags: delphi, tedgebrowser

Delphi 10.4 CE, Win 7/10

`TEdgeBrowser` works fine if I add it to a fresh project.

However, when I add it to a small (1 form) existing project, `TEdgeBrowser.Navigate` fails to load and does not raise an error.

Checking `TEdgeBrowser.LastErrorCode` gives an unknown error of -2147467259.

Have tried setting the `TEdgeBrowser.UserDataFolder` as well as `Form.ActiveControl`.

Comment: As a long time lurker, you have probably seen comments about missing [mre], requests for code to evaluate etc. Please improve your question to include means to reproduce the problem.

Comment: `TEdgeBrowser` requires access to `WebView2Loader.dll` for it to work. I'm guessing this is what you might be missing in your older project. Also it might nit hurt reading Delphi documentation [Using TEdgeBrowser Component](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Using_TEdgeBrowser_Component_and_Changes_to_the_TWebBrowser_Component)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.  Missing WebView2Loader.dll in exe directory.  Props to SilverWarior.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).